# istio v1.9 - istio-proxy envoy config grpc: received message larger than max

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm getting this error message using istio v1.9 on a Kubernetes cluster. I tried searching it online but haven't found anything related to istio, a config that I could modify or an additional log to analyze. Do u have an idea of what could be happening?

I have a few apps running but nothing really big, one pod of a few apps.. not sure which limit I'm reaching here .. could this be an istio limit?

```
istio proxy sidecar log: 
....
....
istio-proxy 2021-02-22T13:44:03.255958Z    warning    envoy config    StreamSecrets gRPC config stream closed: 8, grpc: received message larger than max (XXXXXXX vs. 4194304)
....
```

```
$ istioctl version
fclient version: 1.9.0
control plane version: 1.9.0
data plane version: 1.9.0 (5 proxies)
```

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.3", GitCommit:"1e11e4a2108024935ecfcb2912226cedeafd99df", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-10-14T12:50:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.2", GitCommit:"f5743093fd1c663cb0cbc89748f730662345d44d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-16T13:32:58Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```